# How to get data using yii2 active records and relations?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relationship

I have below code which don't works as exepcted.

Relations specified in model:

```
 public function getShift() {
      return $this->hasOne(Shift::className(), ['id' => 'shift_id']); 
}

public function getShiftName() {
    return $this->shift->name;
}
```

Query:

```
$job_position = JobPositions::find()
            ->innerJoinWith(['shift'])
            ->where('month(date) = month(curdate())')
            ->one();
```

It give me data of on job_position table and not of shift table. How to fetch the data of shift table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use `$job_position->shift`, it will return the related `Shift` object.

You should also read this : [Accessing Relational Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-relational-data).

> When you declare a relation named `xyz` via a getter method `getXyz()`, you will be able to access `xyz` like an object property. Note that the name is case sensitive.